# Do i need to manually set server-side relations when i use Spring Data?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data and SQL Server in my project as backend for angular webapp which is an information website without any heavy algorithms going on- mostly just presents content prepared in CMS, which i also developed.
Since beginning all database structures were created by hand with sql scripts as a simple basic tables with just IDENTITY and Primary Key at ID columns(even at joining tables) and then mapped by Spring annotations to serve it's puropse as intended, i.e. tables as entites with generated values ids, joining tables with cascading feature where needed to make many-to-many relations and so far all works well. 
I reviewed my sql script and at the moment i'm considering if manually setting any Foreign Keys DB server-side will actually help in any way (performance-wise) or rather cause me some now non-existant problems like clashing with SpringData DELETE operations(just guessing)?
Is setting relations server-side when there is ORM framework in use a good or bad practice? If i should set the relations DB server-side if there are any fail-safe rules i should keep in mind doing so? 
 
Additionally- how does joining tables should be indexed in that case? If i have table A and table B (both with PK on IDs) with many-to-many relation joining at AB table and will use it unidirectional(A is my main entity), is it ok to index just AB.A_ID?

Comment: code is main communication between programmers. "Free story" can be interpreded in any way, code is strict

Comment: @JacekCz basically question is code independent- is it in any way needed or advised to mark relations on database server side when i use ORM framework like Spring Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some clarification: You are talking about "Spring annotations" and "SpringData DELETE operations".

The annotations used for mappings are coming from JPA and possibly the JPA implementation (e.g. Hibernate). Spring Data JPA also just delegates to JPA, so again if you are looking into mapping related problems you'll have to look at JPA.

To your actual questions:

> is it in any way needed or advised to mark relations on database server side when I use ORM framework like [JPA]?

Needed? No.

Advised? It depends, but probably yes.

Foreign keys ensure that the database is consistent with respect to the constraints defined by the foreign keys. Especially that a record referenced by an FK is actually there. This is something that is really hard to implement correctly on the client side when you have multiple transactions running concurrently.

Of course, that comes at a cost.

1. The database has to check the constraint whenever you change data.
2. Certain operations have to happen in the correct order. For example, you have to insert a record before you reference it. JPA will normally take care of that for you.

I do not expect any JPA related problems when introducing FKs. And any problems that might arise you probably actually want to know about.

> how does joining tables should be indexed in that case?

The following is based on my knowledge or Oracle, but I'd assume it is very similar to other databases.
By default, any FK column should be indexed. The reason for this is that the DB needs to ensure the consistency and for this, it needs to find and lock rows referencing a given record. Without an index finding such rows will result in table scans and locking will happen on the table level instead of the row level.

> I'm considering if manually setting any Foreign Keys DB server-side will actually help in any way (performance-wise)

You might see performance effects in both directions.

Maintaining the constraints takes some work and might make DML statements slower.

On the other hand, the DB might actually use the knowledge that it will find exactly one row for a foreign key to create better execution plans. Also, the indexes will often also be used for other queries.

If you are loading huge amounts of data in your system you might consider disabling constraints, but it doesn't sound like you are having that use case.

One final note:

Spring Data is really based on the idea of DDD and especially Aggregates. If you buy into that idea you should not have FKs between different Aggregates because those are designed to only be eventually consistent. But this is a big topic and beyond the scope of this question. If you are interested you mind find [this article series interesting](http://scabl.blogspot.de/p/advancing-enterprise-ddd.html).